# Error when generating dynamic Nuxt routes: TypeError: Cannot read property '_normalized' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

To start things off, I don't have any `nuxt-link`s without the `to` attribute.

Now, I have routes like this

- /blog/{category}
- /blog/tag/{tag}
- /blog/{category}/{post}

I have this in my `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
    generate: {
        routes: function() {
            return Promise.all([
                axios.get('https://api.example.com/categories').then(res => {
                    return res.data.map(category => {
                        return {
                            route: '/blog/' + category.slug,
                            payload: category
                        }
                    })
                }),
                axios.get('https://api.example.com/tags').then(res => {
                    return res.data.map(tag => {
                        return {
                            route: '/blog/tag/' + tag.slug,
                            payload: tag
                        }
                    })
                }),
                axios.get('https://api.example.com/posts').then(res => {
                    return res.data.map(post => {
                        return {
                            route: `/blog/${post.category.slug}/${post.slug}`,
                            payload: post
                        }
                    })
                })
            ])
        }
    },
```

When I run `yarn generate`, it starts off good, then around the end it outputs the error from the title, but it doesn't cancel the execution. This is the whole error:

```
 ERROR   undefined                                                                                                                          20:47:14  

TypeError: Cannot read property '_normalized' of undefined
    at normalizeLocation (C:\Users\...\Code\myproject\mysite\node_modules\vue-router\dist\vue-router.common.js:1297:12)
    at VueRouter.resolve (C:\Users\...\Code\myproject\mysite\node_modules\vue-router\dist\vue-router.common.js:2627:18)
    at He (webpack/bootstrap:2:0)
    at async t.default (webpack/bootstrap:2:0)
```

How do I properly generate my dynamic routes for static hosting? This seems quite troublesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll admit I haven't done this before, but based on the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate#function-which-returns-a-promise), it looks like you'd probably need to return a single array. Your promise will resolve to an array of arrays. Maybe something like this:

```js
const buildRoutes = async () => {
  const [r1, r2, r3] = await Promise.all([
    axios.get('https://api.example.com/categories').then(res => {
      return res.data.map(category => {
        return {
          route: `/blog/${category.slug}`,
          payload: category,
        };
      });
    }),
    axios.get('https://api.example.com/tags').then(res => {
      return res.data.map(tag => {
        return {
          route: `/blog/tag/${tag.slug}`,
          payload: tag,
        };
      });
    }),
    axios.get('https://api.example.com/posts').then(res => {
      return res.data.map(post => {
        return {
          route: `/blog/${post.category.slug}/${post.slug}`,
          payload: post,
        };
      });
    }),
  ]);

  return [...r1, ...r2, ...r3];
};
```

And then:

`generate: { routes: buildRoutes }`

Comment: I'm gonna give this a go and report back. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

David is right as far as I know, it needs to be a single array. I had the same issue with an array of arrays not being accepted.

I concat the array further down which is provided by `axios.all`, after fetching from two different endpoints. The API used is Jsonplaceholder, fetching 100 posts and 5000 photos.

Hope this helps.

```js
generate: {
    async routes() {
      const baseURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'

      function postRoutes() {
        return axios
          .get(baseURL + '/posts')
          .then((r) => r.data.map((post) => `post/${post.id}`))
      }

      function photoRoutes() {
        return axios
          .get(baseURL + '/photos')
          .then((r) => r.data.map((photo) => `photo/${photo.id}`))
      }

      const response = await axios
        .all([postRoutes(), photoRoutes()])
        .then(function(results) {
          const merged = [].concat(...results)
          return merged
        })
      return response
    }
  },
```